# How to add shortcut to unity launcher programmatically?

Tags: unity, launcher, qt, quicklists

I'm developing a program in Qt that will help users to manage (create, edit and delete) their quicklists in Unity launcher.

I got to a point where I created .desktop file and I don't know how to programmatically place that file on Unity launcher.

I found two (bad) ways to do this:

1. Manually drag and drop created .desktop file to unity launcher
2. Edit favorites key with "gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites" and force unity to reload with "unity --replace"

So, I'm searching for a function or a system command that is called on first 'drag and drop' method so I can do it in my program without need for user to do it manually.

I don't even know where (or how) to search for my solution so any suggestions will be helpfull.

Comment: I was also looking for it and found it here:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/153597/editing-gsettings-add-icon-to-launcher-by-command

Answer (score 2):

You can add dynamic quicklists at runtime by using DbusMenu. You can read more about that here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI. That page also describes adding counters, progressbars and setting urgency.

Comment: I checked that page out but I haven't found what I'm looking for. I need to find out how to emit the same signal that 'drag and drop' action emits to unity process. I can see that DbusMenu is api for IPC but I still don't know if this can be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

1. Drop the .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`. This way it will appear in the application section as well.
2. Fetch the list of favorites with `gsettings get ...`.
3. Insert the path to the desktop file in the array using `gsettings set`.

The dbus idea by Jo seems nicer though. :)

Comment: This is what I already did but the problem is that unity has to be reloaded with "unity --replace" after a change and that is really ugly.